# Getting error while working with OCR

Tags: c#-4.0

here, i cropped image and stored in "_img". Now i want to catch the data located on _img.
 waiting for your valuable feedback...

```
                MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
                md.Create(Convert.ToString(@"C:/OCR/CroppedNew-1.jpg"));
                 md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
                MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
                string n = image.Layout.Text;

                if (txtInvoiceNum.Text == "")
                {
                    txtInvoiceNum.Text = n;
                }
                else if (txtDocTitle.Text == "")
                {
                    txtDocTitle.Text = n;
                }
                else if (txtDocDescription.Text == "")
                {
                    txtDocDescription.Text = n;
                }
```

from the above code, i'm getting perfect output, but i dont want to store in a folder and i used this below code. for which cannot b catch the image directly

```
               MODI.Image mi = new MODI.Image(_img);
                mi.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
                MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
                string n = image.Layout.Text;

                if (txtInvoiceNum.Text == "")
                {
                    txtInvoiceNum.Text = n;
                }
                else if (txtDocTitle.Text == "")
                {
                    txtDocTitle.Text = n;
                }
                else if (txtDocDescription.Text == "")
                {
                    txtDocDescription.Text = n;
                }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {56F963EC-6EFC-4A6B-9A1E-5BFE545C89D0} failed due to the following error: 80040154(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

Comment: cant catch image directly.. MODI can take image through the image url.. as i described on first code